# Wordpress make "Create custom page" accessible from admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom page template.

```
page_flower-pages.php
```

It appears in the template drop down when i try to add new page.

Now I need to give link for this same behaviour from Admin menu, such that when i click on admin menu link 'Flowers', the page on right side is of 'add new flower'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

that isn't supportet out of the box..

you need to create a custom post-type called "flowers".

Comment: I've tried creating a custome post type Flowers. I managed to add it to menu as well. My problem with this solution is that the permalink is generated as "flowers/rose". I need it to be just "rose", and skip the "flower" slug. Is that possible?